# Point in Polygon: Invalid GIS data provided to function st_within

Tags: mysql, gis, geospatial, polygon, point

I'm trying to determine if a given point is within a polygon through MySQL. I have setup a table called 'municipalities' with the following columns:

```
|  column  |  type   |
|----------|---------|
|    id    |   int   |
|   name   | varchar |
| location | polygon |
```

I have imported a bunch of rows and now I'm trying to find a row where a given point is within the polygon. I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM municipalities 
WHERE st_contains(
    location, 
    ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(50.849243 5.690800)')
);
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error: **"Invalid GIS data provided to function st_within."**.

I'm completely lost as to why I'm getting this error. I'm starting to think that the location column might contain faulty data, but I'm not sure how to check for that.

Can anyone provide some insight into why this query is failing?

<sub>Note: I'm using MySQL 5.7.22</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the EPSG of your point.

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(45 90)', 4326);
```

Make sure that's in the same EPSG of your location data EPSG.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I'm getting the following error:
"Binary geometry function st_contains given two geometries of different srids: 0 and 4326, which should have been identical.". I'm guessing this is because I have not set any EPSG while importing. Is that actually needed?

Comment: @Sander to answer your question concerning the location column validation. You may use two function in MySQL : [st_validate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-validate)  or [St_IsValid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-isvalid). That will give you an idea from where to start !